# Assembly `mov si, ah` produces "invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Tags: assembly, x86-16, instruction-set, operands

So I'm trying to print a character to the screen when I press a key.
I get this error:

> src/kernel/main.asm:20: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

```
mov ah, 00h
int 16h

mov si, ah ;where the error is
```

Comment: SI is 16-bit, AH is 8-bit.  Where do you want the AH bits to go in SI, and what do you want the rest of the bits filled with?  For example, `movsx si, ah` would sign-extend AH into SI.

Comment: Alternatively do `mov al, ah; mov ah, 0; mov si, ax`

Comment: @Sebastian That's fine for unsigned data, but for signed data you can do `CBW AL` followed by `MOV SI,AX`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov si, ah
> ```

The above is mixing an 8 bit operand (`ah`) with a 16 bit operand (`si`). You cannot do that with MOV. When using MOV instruction, operands must be of the same size.

As [Peter suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71721238/assembly-mov-si-al-invalid-combination-of-opcode-and-operands#comment126750308_71721238), you will need to use an instruction like MOVSX or MOVZX if you want to mix operand sizes like that.